# How do you restore a ledger wallet to a software wallet?

Tags: ledger, wallets

I have a Ledger where I installed the Tezos Wallet app. I noted down the recovery phrase.

I tried creating a new wallet in TezBox (or any software wallet) using the recovery phrase the Ledger generated. When I do this it creates a new TZ1 address and I cannot seem to access the address that is in the Ledger wallet.

What is the correct way to do this?

(Note: I'm not implying this is a good idea, I'm just asking in case I were to lose my Ledger device and needed to find a temporary solution to access my funds).